# Summation of styles with same characters wrong coded in css?

Tags: css, styles

I am having trouble with my css which does not seem to be picked up. I am having 3 different types of styles with the same characters. The strange thing is, when I apply `<div class = "block halfleft">..</div>` it displays the right style, but `<div class = "twoblock halfleft">` doesn't seem to work! Any ideas what causes this?

CSS

```
#member {
        padding: 0;
}

#member .block {
        width: 960px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        padding-left:30px;
        height: 475px;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;   
    }   
#member .twoblock {
        width: 960px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-left:75px;
        padding-bottom: 75px;       
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;   
    }
#member .threeblock {
        width: 960px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-left:75px;
        padding-bottom: 75px;       
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;   
    }
#member .block.halfleft, #member .twoblock.halfleft, #member .threeblock.halfleft{
        width: 520px;   
        height: 240px;  
        float: left;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
#member .block.halfright, #member .twoblock.halfright, #member .threeblock.halfright{
        width: 350px;
        height: 240px;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 55px;      

    }
```

PAGE

```
//WORKS://
<div class="block">
    <div class="block halfleft">//text//</div>
        <div class="block halfright">//text//</div>
</div>

//DOESNT WORK BUT WHAT I WANT TO MAKE WORKING://
<div class="twoblock">
    <div class="twoblock halfleft">//text//</div>
        <div class="twoblock halfright">//text//</div>
</div>

//WORKS://
<div class="twoblock">
    <div class="block halfleft">//text//</div>
        <div class="block halfright">//text//</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you got a jsfiddle of a website link?

Comment: I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AZVKm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some padding issues! 75px is getting doubled on .twoblock > .twoblock and in a couple other cases. Simple way to avoid this is to add

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

to all your definitions, which means that padding will be included in the defined width, and not add to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8gzPh/

Comment: I tried that as well, I forgot to put it back to this form, but this also does not work... :s (ps, i'll edit my original post)

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The CSS rule is not getting applied at all?

Comment: I experimented a little bit more, and I found out that the font and font size etc is correct, but that it places the secondblock halfright below the secondblock halfleft instead of next to eachother as it is doing with the block halfleft and block halfright

Comment: Probably that "height: 100%" is causing you issues. 100% of what? Maybe stick to pixel dimensions for height like with your other blocks!

Comment: What are you going for exactly? There's a lot of unclosed strings and broken image links- hard to see what's working and what's broken

Comment: Well, you can see it this way. The thing I am going for is that the text always has to be next to the image, or the image next to the text (they alter). Now you can see that sometimes the image is on one area, and the text is below the image instead of next to it... And I don't get them next to each other with the twoblock style...

Comment: Thanks man! I had to modify some things, I still think it is strange, I don't get why it is working on the block and not on the secondblock, but anyway, It is looking smooth right now :D